# Importar arquivo do phonegap/cordova no eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, apache-cordova

Na hora que eu vou importar arquivo que criei do phonegap/cordova no eclipse não aparece nada.

file>new>project ae eu selecionei Android Project from Existing Code, procuro a pasta que está o projeto do cordova que eu fiz e não aparece nada.

outra informação que acho relevante  é aparecer em vermelho no DDMS isso DeviceMonitor] Sending Tracking request failed!

me deem um help, por favor   :)  obrigada!

Answer (score 1):

Tenta seguir estas etapas:

1. Criar um novo projeto android.
2. Copiar pelo explorer os arquivos (.java, jar, etc)
3. Colar onde esta o novo projeto android.
4. Refresh no projeto no eclipse para listar os arquivos copiados.